# The key parsed from a web page isn't valid when I submit it PHP

Tags: php, html, post, curl, simple-html-dom

I'm programming a script that parses some data from `<a>` and `<input>` tags on the page (using SIMPLE HTML DOM). The web page requires to log in and to hold COOKIES, by the way. I use CURL. The issue appears when I try to submit POST data with the just extracted keys:

```
<input type="HIDDEN" name="KeyStr" value="7241e48c3532f85b1ece8c73f2ab5b3f^91157">
<input type="HIDDEN" name="ParamStr" value="af89a26374cf9addc88f1d5fbfa86670|@|STUD_ID|&amp;|91157|~|GROUP_ID|&amp;|4873|~|GROUP_NAME|&amp;|КН-13-2">  

<a id="TabLeftBorderLink" href="javascript:GoToSubTable(6, '631495a2fe80603ee352b07ead601fdb^2014|1')">Go</a>
```

**("6" and that 3 long keys are extracted)**
The website shows that some key is invalid.

On the another page, where I don't need to POST that "HIDDEN" values, only values from the < a>  tag everything works great.

So I thought the problem was caused by incorrect parsing the chars like & or something like this, maybe.

I've tried:

```
str_replace("&amp;","&",$postdata["ParamStr"]);
//or
str_replace("amp;","",$postdata["ParamStr"]);
```

as well as:

```
$postdata["ParamStr"] = htmlspecialchars_decode($postdata["ParamStr"]);
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: What are you actually posting? What does "it doesn't work" mean?

Comment: `curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,'mode=SubTable&key=$key&TabNo=$postfields["TabNo"]&KeyStr=$postfields["KeyStr"]&TabStr="0|~|2"&ParamStr=$postfields["ParamStr"]');`
It's what I set as postfields.
"It doesn't work" means that it hasn't solved the problem.

Comment: single quote strings don't interpolate the php variables. You should echo that string to see what this means.

Comment: Thank you, I fixed it, but the main problem is still actual.
I think that the "&" character cause the problem, because this character is also a separator between postfields.
But I don't know how to fix it.
I've tried to replace & with '%26', but the key is still invalid.